# integral $\int_{0}^{1}t{}^{q}e^{-iXt}dt$

Tags: analysis

For given $q$ it is easy to compute this integral using integration by parts. 
For general integer(even) $q>0$, Mathematica gives the formula:
$$-Ei[-q,iX]+(ix)^{-1-q}q!$$
where $Ei$ is exponential integral. 
Is  exponential integral related with some known polynomials?

I also need a real and imaginary part of this expression.

Comment: Maple answers this in terms of the incomplete gamma function.  Would you consider that more "known" than the exponential integral function?

Comment: I dont like neither of them :)   If consider integrals $\int_{0}^{1}t^{q}\sin[Xt]dt $ and $\int_{0}^{1}t^{q}\cos[Xt]dt $ the result is generalized hypergeometric functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically the same question as [How to integrate $ \int x^n e^x dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46469/how-to-integrate-int-xn-ex-dx) plus a change of variables.  The answer, for any nonnegative integer $q$,  is 
$$ \left(\frac{i}{X}\right)^{1+q} \left( (-1)^q q! (e^{-iX} - 1) + \sum_{j=1}^q (-1)^{q-j} 
\frac{q!}{j!} (-iX)^j e^{-iX} \right)$$

Comment: this polynomial doesn't have a special name or properties, does it?