# Is there a way to prove $\int {x^n e^x dx} = e^x \sum_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^k \frac{{n!}}{{(n-k)!}}x^{n-k} } + C$ combinatorially?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, integration

In [How to integrate $\int x^n e^x dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46469/how-to-integrate-int-xn-ex-dx), it is shown that

$$\int {x^n e^x dx}  = e^x \sum_{k = 0}^n ( - 1)^k \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}   + C.$$

Since $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ is $P(n,k)$, the number of [$k$-permutations of $n$ objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#In_combinatorics), the right-hand side of this formula smells like the  [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to me.  In fact, the right-hand side is almost the formula for the number of [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#Number_of_permutations_that_are_derangements) on $n$ elements, which is one of the classic examples of the use of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

This would seem to imply that there is some way to interpret $\int x^n e^x dx$ combinatorially such that the right-hand side formula falls out immediately.  However, I haven't been able to see it.  (I don't even know much about combinatorial interpretations of indefinite integration - or even if there are known ways to do so in special cases like this one.)

Does anyone know or see a way to prove 
$$\int {x^n e^x dx}  = e^x \sum_{k = 0}^n ( - 1)^k \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}   + C$$
combinatorially?

*Added:* To clarify, I am looking for a proof that shows that the left- and right-hand sides of the formula count the same thing.  That, to me, is a *combinatorial proof*.

Comment: If you write out the power series for the left and right sides, you will probably get an identity for the coefficient of $x^j$ that can be proven combinatorially.

Comment: See also: http://www.wellesley.edu/Math/pdffiles.d/kayll-colloq.pdf

Comment: @Aryabhata:  Interesting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a solution I quite like which uses inclusion exclusion on a integral over an $n$-dimensional simplex.

First, it is much nicer to consider the definite integral $\int_0^x y^n e^{y} dy$ which will only be off by a constant.  (Which we don't care about anyway)

Consider

$$\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{t_{1}}\cdots\int_{0}^{t_{n}}e^{-t_{n+1}}dt_{n+1}dt_{n}\cdots dt_{1}.$$

This is $e^{-t_{n+1}}$ integrated over the $n$-dimesional simplex. (Only one coordinate is integrated) By [Cauchy's formula for repeated integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration), this is the same as $$\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{x}(x-y)^{n}e^{-y}dy=\frac{1}{n!}e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}y{}^{n}e^{y}dy.$$ Now, we need only show that $$\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{t_{1}}\cdots\int_{0}^{t_{n}}e^{x-t_{n+1}}dt_{n+1}dt_{n}\cdots dt_{1}=e^{x}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k!}x^{k}+C.$$  (A constant will arise since the integrand is not $0$ at $0$) But this follows from splitting up the simplex and using inclusion exclusion.  Here is why:  Integrating $e^{x-t_1}$ over the cube gives $x^ke^x$.  Since the cube can be divided into $k!$ simplicies we get $\frac{x^k}{k!}e^x$.  Now we need to subtract off a correction factor based on the $n-1$-dimensional simplicies, and so on.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 5):

Depends what you mean by "combinatorics."  Does more analytic combinatorics and exponential generating series count?  Lets look at the definite integral $\int_0^x y^ne^y dy$ instead of $\int x^ne^xdx$

Let $a_n=\int_0^x y^n e^y$.  Then $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}=\int_0^x e^{zy+y}dy=\frac{1}{\left(z+1\right)}e^{(z+1)x}-1=e^{x}\left(e^{zx}\left(1+z\right)^{-1}\right)-1.$$

Taking the product of power series we have

$$e^{x}\left(1+zx+\frac{\left(zx\right)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{(zx)^{3}}{3!}\cdots\right)\left(1-z+z^{2}-z^{3}+z^{4}+\cdots\right)-1.$$

$$=e^{x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\right)z^{n}\right)-1$$ and hence by comparing coefficients we conclude $$\int x^{n}e^{x}dx=n!e^x\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}+C.$$

Maybe that helps,

Comment: You missed out on a factor of $e^x$ on the right hand side.

Answer (score 5):

Though it is probably not what you are looking for, I find it relevant to give the following very simple derivation.
So we actually want to prove
$$
\frac{d}{{dx}}e^x \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^k \frac{{n!}}{{(n - k)!}}x^{n - k} }  = x^n e^x .
$$
By the product rule, the left-hand side is given by
$$
e^x \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^k \frac{{n!}}{{(n - k)!}}x^{n - k} }  + e^x \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {( - 1)^k \frac{{n!}}{{(n - k)!}}} (n - k)x^{n - k - 1} ,
$$
or
$$
e^x \bigg(x^n  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {( - 1)^k \frac{{n!}}{{(n - k)!}}x^{n - k} }  + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {( - 1)^k \frac{{n!}}{{(n - k - 1)!}}x^{n - k - 1} \bigg)} ,
$$
or
$$
e^x \bigg(x^n  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {( - 1)^k \frac{{n!}}{{(n - k)!}}x^{n - k} }  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {( - 1)^{k - 1} \frac{{n!}}{{(n - k)!}}x^{n - k} \bigg)} ,
$$
hence by
$$
e^x x^n.
$$

Comment: As you say, this is not really what I am looking for.  I would like to see a combinatorial proof.

Comment: It is a nice and direct non-combinatorial proof, though.

Comment: Thanks. (It was worth posting it in view of the various proofs already given -- here and in the related post.)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find a simple probability argument that's in the spirit of what I was looking for.

First, do a variable switch, with $t = -x$: $\int x^n e^x dx = (-1)^{n+1} \int t^n e^{-t} dt$.

Now, consider the definite version of the second integral, with an extra factor of $\frac{1}{n!}$:  $$\int_0^T \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} dt.$$
This is the probability that the sum of $n+1$ independent exponential(1) random variables (which has an [Erlang (or gamma) distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution#Stochastic_processes)) is less than $T$.

Since interarrival times in a [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) are independent and exponentially distributed, this is also the probability that at least $n+1$ events have occurred by time $T$ in a Poisson process with rate 1.  If $N(T)$ denotes the number of events that occur in $[0,T]$ in a Poisson(1) process, we know that [$P(N(T) = k) = T^k e^{-T}/k!$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process#Homogeneous).  Thus 
$$\int_0^T \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} dt = P(N(T) \geq n+1) = 1 - P(N(T) \leq n) = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^n P(N(T) = k) = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{T^k}{k!} e^{-T}.$$
Switching back in terms of $x$ and multiplying through by $n!$, we have
$$\int x^n e^x dx = - (-1)^{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!} (-x)^ke^x +C = e^x \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \frac{n!}{k!}x^k +C$$
$$= e^x \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k} + C.$$