# Is there a formula for $\int {x^n e^{-x} dx}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I saw in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46469/how-to-integrate-int-xn-ex-dx) question that 
$$
\int {x^n e^x dx}  = \bigg[\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^{n - k} \frac{{n!}}{{k!}}x^k } \bigg]e^x  + C.
$$

and I was wondering if we can get some formula like that for

$$
\int {x^n e^{-x} dx}
$$

when $n \in \mathbb N$. I already know that 
$$
\int^{\infty}_0 {x^n e^{-x} dx} = \Gamma(n+1)
$$

but I'm looking for a general formula.

Comment: Just substitute $-x$ in your formula and account for the extra $(-1)^n$ term that appears.

Comment: This integral is known as the [Incomplete Gamma Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html): $\int x^n e^{-x}{\rm d}x = -\Gamma(n+1,x) + C$.

Comment: @Winther Wrong. The incomplete Gamma is a definite integral. The OP wants an answer without extrema in the integral.

Comment: @FourierTransform Notice the constant $C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general formula is simply $n\to z$ in which $z\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\ t^{z-1}e^{-t}\ \text{d}t = \Gamma(z)$$

Possibly avoid the poles: $z = 0, -1, -2, \ldots$.

If you are talking about a general formula for the indefinite integral, then the series expansion is what you are searching for.

Just expand the exponential in series

$$e^{-x} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}$$

and you'll get the result:

$$\int x^n e^{-x}\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\int x^{n+k}\ \text{d}x$$

Which is

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{1}{n+k+1}x^{n+k+1}$$

Comment: You are confusing the integral with the function $\Gamma(z)$ (which is an analytical continuation of the integral). The latter has poles at negative integers. The former simply does not exist for any $z\leq 0$.