# Expectation of a hitting time

Tags: probability, expected-value, stopping-times

I'm trying to find the expectation of a stopping time. Specifically,

> Let $T_1,...,T_n$ be i.i.d exponential random variables with mean $1$. Let $S_n = T_1 + ... + T_n$ denote their partial sum. Define the stopping time,
>
> $$ T = \inf\{n \geq 1 : S_n \geq 1\}$$
>
> which is the first time $S_n$ exceeds $1$. Calculate $E[T]$.

Here was my approach. Let $x = E[T]$. I want to condition on what happens at the first time $T_1$. If $T_1 \geq 1$, then the process, $\{S_n\}$ has stopped and $T \equiv 1$. Otherwise if $T_1 < 1$, then after one step, process, $\{S_n\}$ will renew again until it reaches $1$. So we have the following equation,

\begin{eqnarray} x &=& E[T]\\ 
&=& E[T | T_1 < 1]P(T_1 < 1) + E[T | T_1 \geq 1]P(T_1 \geq 1)\\
&=& (1+x)P(T_1 < 1) + P(T_1 \geq 1)\\ 
&=& (1+x)(1-e^{-1}) + e^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}

This results in $x = e$.

However, I was told that the answer is $2$. They gave a heuristic explanation that $S_T$ is distributed as $1 + S$ where $S$ is an exponential random variable with mean $1$. I can see the intuition behind this from the memoryless property, but I can't prove why it is so. I ran three simulations in $\textsf{R}$ and got $x \approx 2.001, 2.0161, 1.9785$, which seems to confirm that the answer is $2$. Can someone explain this result?

Also, why/where did my approach fail?

Comment: When you say $\mathbb{E}[T|T_1 < 1] = 1 + x,$ you're asserting that, in expectation, if the first step doesn't get all the way to $1,$ then the remaining steps have to get all the way to $1$. This is clearly false - if $T_1 = 1/2,$ then $T_2 + \dots T_T$ only have to get up to $1/2$. Since $T_1 > 0$ a.s., we should have $\mathbb{E}[T|T_1 < 1] < 1 + \mathbb{E}[T].$

Comment: I noticed that you wanted a non-heuristic proof - note that $\{T > n\} = \{S_n < 1\}$, since the $S_n$ are non-decreasing. It should be straightforward to figure out $\pi_n := P(S_n<1)$ by establishing a recurrence relation between $\pi_n$ and $\pi_{n-1}$ - you'll likely need the volume of a standard simplex in $n$ dimensions. This will directly give you $P(T = n),$ which you can then use to find the mean.

Comment: A more high level argument is from queuing theory - suppose it takes you $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ time to do a job. How many jobs will you finish in $1$ unit of time? It is a classical result that this number is $\mathrm{Poission}(1)$ distributed. However, intuitively, the mean is simpler to argue - your rate of doing jobs is $1$ per unit, so you, in expectation, should finish one job per unit (a Little's law type argument). You are interested in this number plus one - which job will you be doing when the time unit finishes.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you! I was able to do a brute force calculation along these lines.

Comment: ^That's grand, you're welcome :). You should add an answer below, so that others trying the same problem can have a reference.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I added an answer. If someone can confirm the value of that infinite sum, then I think the solution would be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @stochasticboy321's approach, we want to find $P(T > n) = P(S_n < 1)$. Since $S_n = T_1 + ... + T_n \sim$ Gamma($n,1$), we have,

$$ P(S_n < 1) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^1x^{n-1}e^{-x}dx = 1 - \frac{\Gamma(n,1)}{\Gamma(n)}$$

where $\Gamma(n,1)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition). To get this expression, I used the nice identity found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2111109/460426). Finally,

$$ E[T] = 1 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty P(T > n) = 1 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty P(S_n<1) = 1+ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{\Gamma(n,1)}{\Gamma(n)}\right)$$

I have no idea how to evaluate the sum in closed form, but a computation in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1+-+Gamma(n,1)%2FGamma(n),+n+%3D+1+to+infinity) seems to suggest it converges to $1$. Thus, $E[T] = 2$ (at least by conjecture from this numerical computation).

Comment: If we set the integral above to $I_n,$ then by integration by parts, and using $\Gamma(n) = (n-1) \Gamma(n-1) = (n-1)!,$ we get for $n \ge 1,$

$$ P(T > n)  = \frac{I_n}{\Gamma(n)} =  \frac{(n-1) I_{n-1}}{(n-1) \Gamma(n-1)} - \frac{e^{-1}}{{(n-1)!}} = P(T > n-1) - \frac{e^{-1}}{(n-1)!} $$


But then $$P(T = n) = P(T> n-1) - P(T > n) = \frac{e^{-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$ We immediately have that $T \overset{\mathrm{law}}= 1 + Z,$ where $Z \sim \mathrm{Pois}(1),$ and so has mean $2$. Implicitly this also solves the series above (by summation by parts).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Wow I would give a thousand upvotes if it were possible. Thank you!