# Integral with $x^{2017}$ and $e^x$

Tags: integration

How can I evaluate the following integral?
$$\int_{-1}^{1}(|x|+x^{2017})e^{|x|})\,\mathrm dx$$

I found it's
$$2\int_{0}^{1}(x+x^{2017})e^x\,\mathrm dx$$

What can I do next?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegrationbyParts.html OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46469/how-to-integrate-int-xn-ex-dx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint. Revise your work by noting that $x^{2017}e^{|x|}$ is an odd function and $|x|e^{|x|}$ is an even function.