# Integration of $\int x^n e^x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I saw a post asking for the solution of
 $\int x^n e^x dx$ for an arbitrary positive integer $n.$

([How to integrate $ \int x^n e^x dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46469/how-to-integrate-int-xn-ex-dx?newreg=1936828480a34e2587f71a00bfcc8110)) 
In light of that, how does one determine a general solution in terms of a series?

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Do integration by parts

Comment: Why do you want a series? It's an elementary integral, which doesn't necessarily need a series to write.

Comment: After giving n different values and doing integration by parts, I was simply interested in how the integral could be represented by a series.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& \int x^ne^x\,\mathrm dx =\int x^n\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^k}{k!}\,\mathrm dx \\[8pt]
={} & \int\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^{n+k}}{k!}\,\mathrm dx = \sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{k!}\int x^{n+k}\,\mathrm dx \\[8pt]
= {} & C+\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^{n+k+1}}{k!(n+k+1)}
\end{align}

Comment: thank you! @user170231