# Integration Shortcut to Avoid Tedious Integration by Parts

Tags: calculus

In addition to the common integration shortcut of  $\int x \cdot e^{ax}=\frac{xe^{ax}}{a}-\frac {e^{ax}}{a^2}+c$

Is there  supplemental shortcut that can help me to avoid tedious repetitive integration by parts for when I do

$\int x^n\cdot e^{ax}dx$  ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe tabular integration would help if you haven't heard of it? http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/s18/m3357/parts.pdf

Comment: Find the pattern once, prove it using induction, and you'll never have to do it again.

Comment: This page has the formula for $\int x^n e^{x}\, dx$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46469/how-to-integrate-int-xn-ex-dx. You can use this to get the formula for $\int x^n e^{ax}\, dx$ (e.g. substitute $u=ax$ in your integral first, so you'll find you just need to multiply the formula in that post by a certain constant involving $a$ and $n$).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate $ \int x^n e^x dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46469/how-to-integrate-int-xn-ex-dx)

Answer (score 3):

Do enough integrals of the form $\int x^ne^x\,dx$ and you'll notice the answer is $e^x$ times a polynomial of degree $n$. So you could cheat and guess a solution of this form, differentiate it, and match coefficients.

For example, guess
$$\int x^3e^x\,dx=(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)e^x + C.
$$
Differentiate, using the product rule on the RHS:
$$
x^3e^x=[(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) + (3ax^2+2bx+c)]e^x
$$
Match coefficients on $x^3, x^2, \dots$ on down and read off the answer: $$\begin{aligned}a&=1\\b&=-3a=-3\\c&=-2b=6\\d&=-c=-6\end{aligned}$$
(Notice the pattern $-3, -2, -1$ !)

For integrals like $\int x^ne^{ax}\,dx$, reduce to this simpler case by substituting $u:=ax$.

Answer (score 0):

You begin by putting
$$t=ax$$

and for $n\ge 0$, you compute

$$I_n=\int t^ne^tdt$$

As pointed by @Elliot,

$$I_{n+1}=-(n+1)I_n+ t^{n+1}e^t$$